# What are the industry standard breakpoints in Responsive Design based on the most popular devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What are the most popular breakpoints used in responsive design today? My interest is mainly mobile > tablet > desktop.

Note: I feel this is an objective question since popularity is not opinion-based and is measurable.

Thanks!

Edit: This question is not a duplicate as I was asking about sizes "today". The question you quoted is 4 years old and no longer relevant since resolutions are vastly higher. Please remove the "duplicate" message punishment. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The standard for responsive breakpoints are in media queries.

The @media query is 1/3 of the recipe for responsive design. It is the key ingredient that, in it's simplest form, allows specified CSS to be applied depending on the device and whether it matches the media query criteria.

Check this link for more information:
https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints