# What are the industry standard breakpoints in Responsive Design based on the most popular devices TODAY 2016?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What are the most popular breakpoints used in responsive design today? My interest is mainly mobile > tablet > desktop.

No opinions solicited, just hoping for concrete answers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either **too broad, opinion based or requires discussion** and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details. Concrete data is NOT available unless you check **every site on the internet**...you ARE asking for opinions when referring to **popular**

Comment: Please don't repost questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831548/what-are-the-industry-standard-breakpoints-in-responsive-design-based-on-the-mos

Comment: Your question is bad and you should feel bad.

Comment: you are welcome to your "opinion", @Paulie_D, but i think i just got a good answer from Damian Krawczyk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

- Extra small devices Phones (<768px)
- Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
- Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
- Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

[Foundation 6](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/media-queries.html)

- Small: any screen
- Medium: any screen 640 pixels or wider.
- Large: any screen 1024 pixels or wider.

Comment: I didn't think to check the frameworks. Thanks for referencing the two most popular frameworks out there since i'm sure their breakpoints are well researched.